# PHP Youtube API v3 Oauth access token errror

Tags: oauth, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I use this script:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads
to upload videos to youtube. Everything works fine, but next day I have error:

*An client error occurred: The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for responses that were auto-approved.*

I looked at some tips on how to fix this but I did not succeed. I am new to programming. Please help me fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the access type to `offline` which allows you to refresh the access token so you can authenticate the app without the user having to give authorization again.

[Check the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token).

I can't test this now, but try the following. This isn't ideal though, you should be persisting the token somewhere.

```
// After "$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);" add:
$client->setAccessType('offline');


// After "$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);" add:
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $currentTokenData = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
    if (isset($currentTokenData->refresh_token)) {
        $client->refreshToken($currentTokenData->refresh_token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me. What I must edit in this script  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#resumable_uploads ??? Where I can get $refresh_token